# cannot use Debug with old Xcode 3.1

Tags: xcode, macos, debugging, xcode3.2

I have a mac os x application, which was developed in Xcode 3.1.1, now I need to re-develop it.

Of course, I cannot build it in the newest Xcode 4.5, and it's hard for me to change the settings to make it work in Xcode 4.5.

So I downloaded the Xcode 3.1.1, it builds ok. But I just cannot use the debugging. The nslog can display normally in the console. I need to debug.

Anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Presumably you mean Xcode 3.1.1, not Xcode 3.3.1 ?

Comment: Yes. It is 3.1.1, I edited the miss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Xcode 3.2.6 - it still runs fine on Lion and Mountain Lion (I use it daily on Mountain Lion) and it should be able to build and debug your legacy project without any changes.

Comment: I cannot debug in OS X 10.8, but I can debug in the old mac (10.6.8)